# How to limit PHP-FPM memory usage?

Tags: php, memory-usage, php-fpm

I'm running an Ubuntu 10.04 nginx webserver with PHP-FPM. It has 512MB of total memory (256MB swap). After starting the PHP-FPM process (`/etc/init.d/php5-fpm start`), it uses an acceptable ~100MB for about 5 children. But then the processes suddenly balloon to using 400MB.

[Here's a graph of my server's memory usage with PHP-FPM.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOjpd.png)

[Here's my PHP process memory usage (`ps aux | grep php`)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOHto.png)

I have set my PHP-FPM config conservatively: `pm = static` and `pm.max_children = 5`.
I'm only running a few Wordpress blogs, and I don't get that many visitors.

How can I **control the memory usage of PHP-FPM's processes** so it doesn't eat up my server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Disable any PHP extensions that you don't need.
- Set a low max requests per child so each process is restarted more often.
- Reduce the number of processes. You don't need many for a small blog. 2 should be fine.

Comment: I set the max requests to 4 and the number of processes to 3. Now my memory usage looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/jChLX.png

Comment: Max requests is really too low. The processes will be restarted too often (too much CPU time wasted). I would suggest 32 max requests/child and 2 processes. Try and see which PHP extensions are causing the high memory usage too; it shouldn't really be that high in the first place.

Comment: It is a good thing to have high buffer/cache usage by the way. This memory can be freed by the OS if needed but will improve performance if not needed.